# What are some good books/sites to learn research methodology in Mathematics?

Tags: book-recommendation, research

I have to study a course named $\textbf{Research Methodology}$ in my course work. Also I want to gain a depth knowledge for doing research in mathematics like how research papers are written and published in mathematics, how to get access through mathematics journals, what are virtual libraries, how to search problems in your topic, how to know about other mathematicians, what is citation and in short everything about research related topics.

The main topics in our Course work are:

> Scientific research and literature survey.
> History of mathematics, finding and solving research problems, role of a supervisor, survey of a research topic, publishing a paper, reviewing a paper, research grant proposal writing, copyright issues, ethics and plagiarism.

> Research tools. Searching google (query modifiers), MathSciNet, ZMATH, Scopus, ISI Web of Science, Impact factor, h-index, Google Scholar, ORCID, JStor, Online and open access journals, Virtual library of various countries.

> Scientific writing and presentation. Writing a research paper, survey article, thesis writing; LaTeX, PSTricks, Beamer, HTML and MathJaX
> Software for Mathematics. Mathematica/Matlab/Scilab/GAP

I searched some of these topics online and got some knowledge to some extent
but I am not fully satisfied.
I tried to find out some books where I could get all these topics in detail.

Some guy suggested me the book named :$ \textbf
 {How to write Mathematics by Norman E. Steenrod, Paul R. Halmos,
 AMS, (1973)}$

This book solved some of the problems but still I am trying to find some more material and content to gain very good knowledge about everything.

I know this is the best place to get answers of this  type of questions

Anyone who went through these topics and know the places where I could get some help..Please suggest me.

I would be greatly thankful to all those.

Comment: That's a very long list of topics many of which would take a substantial length of time to master. The best you can hope for from such a course is to learn that those tools exist. I would hope that your instructor or the person who designed the course will provide references and resources.

Comment: Several of the following questions in the *Academia* Stack Exchange will be helpful -- [google site:academia.stackexchange.com-search for mathematics + research + methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematics+research+methods+site:academia.stackexchange.com). FYI, for some reason this question appeared near the top of the queue for me when I glanced at the "new questions" queue, and I didn't realize that this was over 6 years old until **after** I had obtained this google search link. However, I'm posting it anyway in case others stumble on your question and would benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should try "A Student's Guide to the study, practice and tools of modern mathematics" by Donald Binder and Martin Erickson. For the rest of thing you can search independently on internet.